# How to customize an embed using args in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a command to send an embed but I can't figure out how to customize an embed using arguments

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    category: 'Role Select Msg',
    description: 'Sends a embeded message for roles or for announcemnts',

    permissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],

    slash: 'both',
    guildOnly: true,

    minArgs: 2,
    expectedArgs: '<channel> <text>',
    expectedArgsTypes: ['CHANNEL', 'STRING'],

    callback: ({ message, interaction, args }) => {
        const channel = message ? message.mentions.channels.first() : interaction.options.getChannel('channel')
        const description = interaction.options.getString('text')
        if (!channel || channel.type !== 'GUILD_TEXT'){
            return 'Please tag a text channel.'
        }

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(description)

        channel.send(embed)

        if(interaction){
            interaction.reply({
                content: 'Sent message!',
                ephemeral: true
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I want to customize something like a title or description based on what someone that used the command input for .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the easiest way that I have found to customize an embed using user input is just to use args[] and pass in the array placement of the expected args.

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    category: 'Role Select Msg',
    description: 'Sends a embeded message for roles or for announcemnts',

    permissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],

    slash: 'both',
    guildOnly: true,
    testOnly: true,

    minArgs: 2,
    expectedArgs: '<channel> <title>',
    expectedArgsTypes: ['CHANNEL', 'STRING'],

    callback: async ({ interaction, args }) => {
        const channel = interaction.options.getChannel('channel')
        if (!channel || channel.type !== 'GUILD_TEXT'){
            return 'Please tag a text channel.'
        }

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(args[1])

        channel.send({embeds: [embed]})

        return `Message sent to ${channel}`
```

if someone put in any text for the <.text.> expected arg it will set it as the title with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

for a normal message command you can use `args` or `split` and `collector` for example:

```js
// Defining the channel you want to send the embed to
const channel = await message.mentions.channels.first() || message.guild.channels.cache.get(args[0]) || message.channel;

// Defining the first embed
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`Please type your title and description separated by a \`+\`, __example:__ Title+Description`)
const msg = await message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})

// Using message collector to collect the embed's title and description
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id //Filter the message of only the user who run the command
                
message.channel.awaitMessages({
     filter,
     max: 1,
     time: 120000,
     errors: ["time"]
   }).then(async collected => {
           const msgContent = collected.first().content
           const embedFields = msgContent.split('+'); // You can use any symbol to split with not only +
           const customEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
               .setTitle(`${embedFields[0]}`)
               .setDescription(`${embedFields[1]}`)
               .setFooter({text: `${embedFields[2]}`})
           channel.send({embeds: [customEmbed]}) // send the embed to the channel
           message.reply({content: `Your embed was sent to ${channel}`})
}) // reply to the main command
```

If it was an interaction command, You can use `Options`:

```js
// Defining the options
const channel = interaction.options.getChannel('channel')
const title = interaction.options.getString('title') // Title of the embed
const descr = interaction.options.getString('description') // Description for the embed
// You can add also add a custom footer:
const footer = interaction.options.getString('footer')

//Now it's simpler than using a normal message command
const customEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`${title}`)
    .setDescription(`${descr}`)
    .setFooter({text: `${footer}`})
channel.send({embeds: [customEmbed]})
interaction.reply({content: `Your embed was sent to ${channel}`, ephemeral: true}) // reply to your interaction
// Of course you need to add the options to the interaction, and check it required option or not
```

Example of the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJsj9.png

Comment: Thank you so much your answer helped me so much. But I did figure out that if I just used an args array I can pass that into the embed and it works the same exact way. Is there any issue with using it this way because it is a lot simpler and easier to set up and use?

Comment: Not at all, as I said in my answer you can use `args` the same way, you can also add a custom color for your embed but you'll need to use reg to check if the hex code is valid or your bot will crash

Comment: Also can you check the answer as correct answer so people can easily find an answer

Answer (score 0):

After doing some trial and error, I've found one of some solutions for your problem.

````
if(message.author.id == "") {
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription("To create a customized embed, you need to do an `args[0]` and `args[1]`")
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setTimestamp()

        message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})

        const msg_filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
        const collector = await message.channel.createMessageCollector({filter: msg_filter, max: 2, timer: 15000})

        collector.on('end', collected => {
            let i = 0;
            collected.forEach((value) => {
                i++;
                if (i === 1) embed.setTitle(value.content);
                else if (i === 2) embed.setDescription(value.content);
            })
            console.log(i)
            message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
        })
    } else {
        return message.reply("```Only the Developer Can use these command.```")
    }
````

To achieve these kind of command, You need to use a `collector function`
[See more here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors)

Using `max: 2` makes it to wait for `two args` which is the `arsg[0]` and `args[1]`, Then use any `++` so you can make it to `equal` for `.setTitle` and `.setDescription`

Comment: I realized I can just use the args[] straight from the expected args and pass that into the embed and it works the same.